# Send exit limit order on exchange when entry signal is triggered

Tags: pine-script

I have made a scalper BOT and I want to know if when the entry alert is triggered I can also send the Limit take profit order on the exchange (using wunderbit as a link between tradingview and bybit), right now it only send the limit order when the strategy.exit take profit level is reached, but as a take profit based on risk reward ratio, is a level already known at the entry of the position. I want to do this to already have the limit order on my exchange ready to be filled.

```
//Exit trades when stop or target is hit    
strategy.exit(id='Long Exit', from_entry='Long', limit=tradeTargetPrice, stop=tradeStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size > 0)    
strategy.exit(id='Short Exit', from_entry='Short', limit=tradeTargetPrice, stop=tradeStopPrice, when=strategy.position_size < 0)
```

tradeTargetPrice is a TP level calculated based on the RR ratio.
Is there any command or alert to send the limit order before the price trigger the alert?

Comment: If you know the profit target level before open position, you could add this TP command after entry command in one message. If this is not true, you can use the `alert()` function in your strategy for sending TP command when a conditions are met.

Comment: What do I have to put as command for tp on my entry alert? Can you confirm me that in this way, the order will be submitted as limit order and not close at market price? Thanks!

Comment: What is a "broker-bridge" do you use? For example alertatron.com (https://alertatron.com/docs/include-current-price-and-more-in-your-alerts) allow send TP+SL with entry command simultaneously.

Comment: Right now I'm using Wunderbit as a broker-bridge and another strange thing is that when limit orders are selected the entry order is triggered as limit but the TP is always sent as a market order.